# pandas: load multiple files into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have six CSV files for six different years and I'd like to combine them into a single dataframe, with the column headers appropriately labelled.

Each raw CSV file looks like this (e.g. 2010.csv)

```
state,gender,population
FL,m,2161612
FL,f,2661614
TX,m,3153523
TX,f,3453523
...
```

And this is the structure I'd like to end up with:

```
state    gender    population_2010   population_2012   population_2014  .....
FL       m         2161612           xxxxxxx           xxxxxxx          .....
FL       f         2661614           xxxxxxx           xxxxxxx          .....
TX       m         3153526           xxxxxxx           xxxxxxx          .....
TX       f         3453523           xxxxxxx           xxxxxxx          .....
```

How can I do this efficiently? Currently I have this:

```
df_2010 = pd.read_csv("2010.csv")
df_2012 = pd.read_csv("2012.csv")
...

temp = df_2010.merge(df_2012, on=("state", "gender"), how="outer", suffixes=("_2010", "_2012")
temp1 = temp.merge(df_2014, on=("state", "gender"), how="outer", suffixes=(None, "_2014")
... repeat five more times to get the final dataframe
```

But I feel there must be a better way.

Comment: Disclaimer: I barely dabbled into pandas so the following might be wrong and should be taken as a grain of salt but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe) should have the answer that you're looking for which uses `pd.concat()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try concat on axis 1 after setting state and gender as index

```
l = ['2010.csv','2012.csv']
out = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file).set_index(['state','gender'])
        .add_suffix(file.split(".")[0]) for file in l),axis=1)
out = out.reset_index() #finally reset the index if needed
```

Note that if you have the original path of the files, you may need to replace `file.split(".")[0]` with something like `os.path.split` to grab the filename without extension

Comment: Thank you! That's very close, but doesn't rename the column headers.

Comment: @Richard I manually types it out but add_suffix should do the trick, try `pd.DataFrame({"population":[1,2,3]}).add_suffix("_2010")` to see how it works. You can adjust the filename split accordingly